# JSF Facelets License

Tags: java, jboss, richfaces, facelets, seam2

We're currently using richfaces as part of the Seam 2.2.0.GA framework. We're currently having a problem with the jsf-facelets.jar which is added by Seam, and which comes with the CDDL software license which is problematic to the proprietary software that we develop. So far, I have replaced other jars successfully replaced `jsf-api.jar` for instance with [this one](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.spec.javax.faces/jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec/2.0.1.Final)

jsf-facelets.jar is needed for a successful deployment of our richfaces application. My question is: Is there another implementation of the jsf-facelets.jar with a "better" license? I already saw the Apache MyFaces, but I think that I would have to do so many changes to the existing project, which is something that I'm still reluctant to do for now. We're using JBoss 5 for deployment.

Comment: The Richfaces community is helping me on this as well:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/229449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked out the source code from https://svn.java.net/svn/facelets~svn/trunk (You need to create an account on java.net to checkout the code)

The source is using the Apache Lisence V2.0